# Избавиться от NPE

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, textview, android-textview

Нужна помощь. Как дополнить код, чтобы не выбивало NPE?

```
public class Tab1Mon extends Fragment {

   TextView tv;
   Calendar date;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1mon, container, false);
       tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.monFirstText2);
       changeText();
       return v;
   }

   public void changeText() {
       Calendar dateFeb3 = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 1, 13);

       if (date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) == dateFeb3.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) &&
               date.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dateFeb3.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
           tv.setText("Текст1");
       } else {
           tv.setText("Текст2");
       }


  }
}
```

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инициализировать поле:

```
Calendar date;
```

Из-за того, что оно не инициализировано, вылетает NPE в этом вызове:

```
date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
```